# Detect tap on static UITableViewCell in Xamarin Studio

Tags: c#, ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios

I've set up a static table with iOS designer in Xamarin Studio. Now I want to display a new view controller if a user taps on a specific cell.

How can I detect the tap?

I saw implementations for Objective-C which uses the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method but than I also would have to implement the data source together with the `GetCell` (or `cellForRowAtIndexPath` in Objective-C world) method. If I do that I have again to implement the content of my static cells in code and than I have dynamic prototype cells (no static table view anymore). The reason is that I have to create a new cell or dequeue an existing one. I already have set an identifier for each cell. Working with iOS Designer (Interface Builder in Objective-C world) is for nothing if I couldn't do that.

What are my options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have found the problem. It is possible to use `RowSelected` without data source. I set up again my static table and now it works. It seems that I somehow introduced an error into iOS designer.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting scenario.  I don't have my tools in front of me, but I supposed you might be able to do something like the following if you cells are truly static and aren't going to be changed (added to or removed):

1. Sublcass UITableViewCell for each of the static cells you have.
2. Assign the subclasses to the prototype cells
3. Within each of the subclasses, create an instance of a UITapGesturesRecognizer.
4. Add the UITapGestureRecognizer to the GestureRecognizers collection.

Once again, not verified.  This would be how I might go about giving this a try.